# Kafka stream to count how many times a property value appears

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I am new to Kafka stream and puzzled by how to design a topology to implement this requirement:

My incoming streaming records have keys. Each key occurs exactly two times.
First time, the data is like:
`<key> : {"sender": <Name>}`
And the second time the value is null:
`<key> : null`
indicating that the signal is cancelled.

For example, the following is an example of the incoming stream:

```
"key_1" : {"sender":"Bob"}
"key_2" : {"sender":"Alice"}
"key_2" : null
"key_3" : {"sender":"Bob"}
"key_3" : null
"key_1" : null
```

I need to write a Kafka stream application to count how many signals are on for each sender. For example, for the above incoming stream, my application is supposed to output:

```
Bob : 1
Alice : 1
Alice : 0
Bob : 2
Bob : 1
Bob : 0
```

What should the topology be like to implement this? I feel join might be needed, but we don't know how long the signal last (the time between the two records of a same key).

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out. It is a basic case of KTable aggregation:

```
inputStream
        .toTable()
        .groupBy((key, event) -> KeyValue.pair(getSender(event), 1L),
            Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()).withName("group-senderId")
        )
        .count();
```